# Why are the TrackballControls backwards when applied to an object other than camera?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Like the title says, the TrackballControls don't work properly when I apply them to a sphere mesh. It works backwards, so lateral dragging moves the sphere vertically, and vice versa.

Can someone kindly tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the cleanest way of implementing this but... have you tried doing this?

```
controls.rotateSpeed = - 1.0;
```

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work. Thanks though. Someone in the chat room correctly suggested that I can achieve what I need by continuing to use a camera trackball, and using sprites for my labels. For the record, the trackball control really shouldn't accept any Object3D parameter; it clearly is designed to accept a camera.